# variable length array error when passing array using template deduction

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

Hi when compiling the following I am getting an error. I am unsure why this is, if I change these to const values like [10][20] it works but doesn't seem to like the variable even though this a declaration so it is not subject to changing the dimensions.  I am confused why this is error is occurring please help. See code below:

```
#include <iostream>

template <size_t X, size_t Y>
void fun (int (&array)[X][Y])
{
    std::cout << " do something fun " << std::endl;
}

int main ( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
  size_t row (10);
  size_t col (20);

  int data1[10][20];
  fun ( data1 );// compiles

  int data2[row][col];
  fun ( data2 );// fails

  return 0;
}




g++ -I/usr/include -I/usr/local/include -std=c++11 -pthread -O3 -Wall -c main.cpp -o main.o
main.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
main.cpp:18:15: error: no matching function for call to ‘fun(int [(((sizetype)(((ssizetype)row) + -1)) + 1)][(((sizetype)(((ssizetype)col) + -1)) + 1)])’
main.cpp:18:15: note: candidate is:
main.cpp:4:6: note: template<long unsigned int X, long unsigned int Y> void fun(int (&)[X][Y])
main.cpp:4:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:18:15: note:   variable-sized array type ‘int [(((sizetype)(((ssizetype)row) + -1)) + 1)][(((sizetype)(((ssizetype)col) + -1)) + 1)]’ is not a valid template argument
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
```

Comment: variable sized arrays are not valid C++, it's an extension provided by compilers. Chances are the template can't be deduced since it isn't in compile time.

Comment: int data2[row][col] is not standard C++. gcc/clang accept it though. This is one among other features that exist in C99 but not adopted in C++03 or C++11

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`int data2[row][col];` is not standard C++, since `row` and `col` are not constant expressions. Your compiler has an extension that allows you to use arrays with non-constant dimensions, but such a beast can't match a template signature that expects a normal array with constant dimensions.

Given that `row` and `col` don't actually vary in your program, in this instance you can avoid the issue altogether by declaring them `const` so that `row` and `col` *are* constant expressions:

```
int main ( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
  const size_t row (10);
  const size_t col (20);

  int data1[10][20];
  fun ( data1 );// compiles

  int data2[row][col];
  fun ( data2 );// compiles too!

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I did try this originally this is a simplified example I had the dimensions as the a vector size so I tried the following  where   const size_t row ( vec1.size() ) and it failed

Comment: Yep - there's no way to create an array with a runtime dimension, since an array is by definition something with static extent. The C99/C++14 extensions for arrays of runtime dimension are really overloading the array syntax to create a different kind of animal altogether. Write `fun` so that it takes a vector, or an arbitrary container, or a pair of iterators.

Comment: "there's no way to create an array with a runtime dimension" - that's exactly what gcc *is* doing here, the real issue is that there's no way to instantiate a template based on runtime parameters; instead, the language provides functions (that aren't templated, and can't deduce array dimensions).

Comment: @TonyD I'm making a semantic argument that something with runtime dimension is definitionally not an array. Calling it an array doesn't make it one. If it was an array, you could use it as an array all the time, instead of only some of the time. I should probably just capitulate to the heavy overloading of the term "array" and instead say "array of static extent".

Comment: Well, you'd be fighting all the gcc/clang docs there, and with std::array added into the terminological quagmire, "of static extent" is probably a good way to go.

Comment: Thanks guys for all the help / answers. I decided to use a vector and just use numRows * numCols as the dimension with row * numCols + col as the index lookup. This helps with contiguous memory access as well and prefetching.