# Getting iterator for an array with a constant length in c++

Tags: c++, arrays

I read on another stackoverflow post ([variable length array error when passing array using template deduction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17893184/variable-length-array-error-when-passing-array-using-template-deduction)) that the following should be possible:

```
#include <iostream>

int input() {
    int a;
    std::cin>>a;
    return a;
}

int main()
{
   const int b = input();

  int sum[b];
  std::begin(sum);
}
```

Except that it doesn't seem to work, I still get an similar error.

```
 In function 'int main()': 
16:17: error: no matching function for call to 'begin(int [b])' 
16:17: note: candidates are:
```

Followed by information on possible templates it could fit.

Comment: `#include <iterator>`. But, don't use C-style array - so `#include <vector>` instead.

Comment: `input()` is not a constant expression.

Comment: `#include <iterator>` Did not solve it. Is it possible to make the result of cin  constant? I suppose it is switching to vectors than.

Comment: @Yadeses Not compile-time constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `std::begin(sum)` only when `sum` is regular array, not when it is a variable length array.

The following is OK.

```
const int b = 10;
int sum[b];
std::begin(sum);
```

In your case, `b` is not known at compile time. For arrays whose length are not known at compile time, it's better to use `std::vector` instead of relying on a compiler specific extension. The following is OK.

```
const int b = input();  // You can use int b, i.e. without the const, also.
std::vector<int> sum(b);
std::begin(sum);
```